# create horizontal bar chart

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a horizontal bar chart in a web-page using php,mysql,javascript,css,html and 'wamp server',editor: 'Macromedia Dreamweaver',browser: 'Mozilla Firefox';

---

i want to read data(semister results) from table,and display data through bar chart like,
[image]

---

- *Database name* `exam`
- *Table name* `'sem_result'` contain following columns>> `regno[Primary key], uid, reg_date, exam_date, sem, result;`

---

php code is::

```
<?php
// Connect to server
$cn=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
//Connect to Database
mysql_select_db("exam") or die(mysql_error());
//sql query
$sql="SELECT result FROM sem_result WHERE uid=11111";
//collect results
$result=mysql_query($sql,$cn);
//read data if found
$counter=0;
while($rd=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 $sem_result[$counter]=$rd[0]; //save sem results into array
 $counter=$counter+1;
}
//display
echo "<table>
<tr>
    <td>sem1</td>
    <td width='100px'>
      <img src='img/menu_back.png' width='".$sem_result[0]."%' height='15px'/>
    </td>
    <td>".$sem_result[0]."%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>sem2</td>
    <td width='100px'>
      <img src='img/menu_back.png' width='".$sem_result[1]."%' height='15px'/>
    </td>
     <td>".$sem_result[1]."</td>
</tr>
</table>";
//close database
mysql_close($cn);
 ?>
```

---

if results are 78.95%,78.10%  ,bar chart shows both result are equal, i.e 78%; 
 image width become 78%,not 78.95% please help to fix this problem.

Comment: What you describe is the correct behavior as in HTML the browser rounds down to the pixel (floor). You might want to instead round in a different way. If so, round the percentage values your own before inserting them into the HTML. http://php.net/round - Keep in mind that you can only round to a full pixel anyway, that is, there are 100 steps only. not 10 000 steps as you imply with two decimal digits.

Comment: You can use `highchart`. its one of the best chart API. click link for tutorials. http://spjoshis.blogspot.in/search/label/Highcharts

Comment: ok,But how to imply this. is there any other way to create this bar chart.

Comment: is it possible without jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hakre already pointed out, you can't get any more precise than a single pixel or percentage, ie you can't have 78.5px or 78.5%... however, you still have some options without javascript. First, I'm not sure why you are using an image for the green bar, why not just pure html/css? Either way, here's my suggestion:

Get the total width of the bar graph, from 0 - 100, in pixels. Just by eyeballing the image you posted, I'm gonna call it 325px:

```
$total_width = '325';
```

Then, set each bar's width as such:

```
$bar_width = round($total_width * ($sem_result[0] / 100));
```

This way, a stored value of 78.10% will end up as 254px, and 78.95% will be 257px. It is still not the exact percentage, but it is closer. The longer the total width of your graph, the more precise you calculation will be.

Answer (score 1):

change table name and column name and progress.png image.
after that use it.

`

```
<?php $s="select count(*) as tnum from leakage";
$r=mysql_query($s) or die (mysql_error());
while($rw=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
echo $tno=$rw['tnum'];
}
?>

<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
 <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
 <th>No.Of Leakage</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php 
  $sql1="select dept,count(dept) as total from leakage where dept='winding'";
 $result1=mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
 {

 $dept=$row['dept'];
  $tot=$row['total'];
 }                                  
 ?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $dept; ?></td>
 <td width="100%"><img src="assets/images/progress.png" width="<?php   echo (($tot/$tno)*100);?>" height="20px"><?php echo $tot;?>%</td>

 </tr>

 <?php 
   $sql2="select dept,count(dept) as total from leakage where dept='spining'";
   $result2=mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
   {

  $dept=$row['dept'];
 $tot=$row['total'];
  }     
  ?>
   <tr>
 <td><?php echo $dept; ?></td>
  <td width="100%"><img src="assets/images/progress.png" width="<?php echo (($tot/$tno)*100);?>" height="20px"><?php echo $tot;?>%</td>

    </tr>
   <?php 
    $sql5="select count(dept) as total from leakage";
    $result5=mysql_query($sql5) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result5))
   {

     $tot=$row['total'];
   }        
   ?>
   <tr>
   <td>Total</td>
       <td width="100%"><img src="assets/images/progress.png" width="<?php echo $tot;?>" height="20px"><?php echo $tot; ?></td>
     </tr>
      </table>
```

`